# WinDbg: How do I avoid Address/Instruction Breakpoints Getting Hit by the Wrong Thread?

Tags: multithreading, debugging, windbg

### Dynamic One-Shot Breakpoints Hit in Incorrect Thread(s)

I'm attempting to monitor all malloc/free usage in an app with disparate DLLs, some of which I do not manage.

My thought was to put a breakpoint in malloc that emits the desired allocation size and have that create a breakpoint on the return address and emit the returned pointer. That dynamically used breakpoint is causing me problems. It keeps getting hit by different threads, even though in the breakpoint definition, I specifically said which thread it applies to.

Here's a simple application that exhibits the fundamental problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>


void malloc_loop( int num_iterations ) {
    for (int i=0; i<num_iterations; i++) {
        size_t size = rand() % 200;
        char *p = (char*)malloc(size);
        free(p);
    }
}


int main() {
    int num_iterations=10000000;
    int i;

    srand(time(NULL));

    DebugBreak();

    std::thread r1(&malloc_loop,num_iterations);
    std::thread r2(&malloc_loop,num_iterations);
    std::thread r3(&malloc_loop,num_iterations);
    std::thread r4(&malloc_loop,num_iterations);

    DebugBreak();

    r1.join();
    r2.join();
    r3.join();
    r4.join();

    return 0;
}
```

If I run the application in the debugger (windbg or cdb), I go to the second breakpoint (after the worker threads have been created), and set a breakpoint like

```
~4 bp40 ucrtbase!malloc ".printf \"[0x%08x] malloc(%d): \", dwo(@esp), dwo(@esp+4); ~4 bp499 /1 dwo(@esp) \".printf \\\"0x%08x\\\\n\\\", @eax; gc\"; gc "
```

It should print `[<return_addr>] malloc(<alloc_size>):` then create a breakpoint on return that prints the pointer value.

This should cause only one of the worker threads (the process contains 4 threads before I create mine) to break.

If I continue with that breakpoint in place, the session will run for a short while then break on the return address of a previous malloc, but in the wrong thread (which also doesn't run my "handler" code, which should automatically continue).

Here's a typical session

```
0:000> ~
.  0  Id: 3010.5afc Suspend: 1 Teb: 01169000 Unfrozen
   1  Id: 3010.2b98 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0116c000 Unfrozen
   2  Id: 3010.4810 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0116f000 Unfrozen
   3  Id: 3010.6498 Suspend: 1 Teb: 01172000 Unfrozen
   4  Id: 3010.4160 Suspend: 1 Teb: 01175000 Unfrozen
   5  Id: 3010.3ce4 Suspend: 1 Teb: 01178000 Unfrozen
   6  Id: 3010.4c80 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0117b000 Unfrozen
   7  Id: 3010.5630 Suspend: 1 Teb: 0117e000 Unfrozen
0:000> ~4 bp40 ucrtbase!malloc ".printf \"[0x%08x] malloc(%d): \", dwo(@esp), dwo(@esp+4); ~4 bp499 /1 dwo(@esp) \".printf \\\"0x%08x\\\\n\\\", @eax; gc\"; gc "
0:000> g
[0x00d7105b] malloc(88): 0x013c1568
[0x00d7105b] malloc(26): 0x013c6ea8
[0x00d7105b] malloc(157): 0x013c0958
[0x00d7105b] malloc(132): [0x00d7105b] malloc(132): breakpoint 499 exists, redefining
[0x00d7105b] malloc(132): breakpoint 499 exists, redefining
0x013c12d0
[0x00d7105b] malloc(169): [0x00d7105b] malloc(169): breakpoint 499 exists, redefining
0x013c0d20
[0x00d7105b] malloc(154): 0x013c12d0
(3010.5630): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=013c6ea8 ebx=013c0fb0 ecx=43b388fd edx=40000060 esi=00d719c0 edi=013c0fb0
eip=00d7105b esp=01dffb40 ebp=01dffb50 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
malloc_rand_loop_mt+0x105b:
00d7105b 83c404          add     esp,4
```

Note that the thread that is hitting the breakpoint (5630) is *not* the one I specified (4160). I can continue (`g`) over and over from here, and every 5-20 times through, this "false hit" will occur.

Am I misunderstanding how breakpoints should work?

I'm creating a one-shot breakpoint for a specific thread. The "false hit" looks like it's at the corresponding return address from the previous breakpoint (#40), but it's not running any of the handler code.

Is it possible that the breakpoint is being partially created (and hit) before it is completely created (and the thread-id limitation and handler code imposed)?

Can I create a disabled breakpoint, configure it, then enable it? (I don't see refs in the documentation that describe creating disabled breakpoints.)

I'm also a little troubled by the redefinition warnings, "breakpoint 499 exists, redefining," since the breakpoint shouldn't exist any time it gets created (how could the same thread call malloc from within malloc)? I don't know what to make of this.

**Can anyone help me understand what's happening in the debugger or how to avoid having "false hits" by other threads?**

Comment: Have you consider freezing other threads?

Comment: Maybe conditionnal breakpoint might work. Not sure if one could make a condition to check the thread ID from the code. Otherwise, temporary change to the code might be the easy way to be able to properly debug.

Comment: @Phil1970 I considered something like this, but the breakpoint is getting hit without running the "handler" code. I suspect that putting a condition in the handler would be ineffective. This seems like a bug, but IDK.

Comment: By the way, are you debugging a DEBUG version of your code? Optimized code (RELEASE) will often share common code and not have a one-to-one relation between original code and assembly instruction which make debugging very hard. Thus an actual breakpoint might match multiple source lines or a source line might not allows any breakpoints. If debugging is weird, this is the first thing to verify.

Comment: If I don't care about source code matching, should I expect badness merely because optimization is on? I'm only breaking on instruction address(es).

Comment: When a compiler optimize the code, one-to-one relation is lost so breakpoints and stepping code is affected in a way that can be hard to understand for a human. **Easy debugging  is the main reason of having non optimized code**

Comment: Freezing threads sounded promising. However, if I freeze them, create the breakpoint, then thaw them, the behavior persists. I tried suspend/resume, too, with no difference in behavior.

Comment: I tried the above example with DEBUG defined and all optimizations disabled. No difference in behavior.

Comment: Why do this by thread and not by DLL (call stack)? Use UMDH to monitor all mallocs, then remove the ones which don't have the particular DLL on the call stack